# "Sec." instead of "Chap." with bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am using bibtex to organize the bibliography of a document. One of the references is the following:

[image: Reference which I would like to modify]

and here is the corresponding entry in the .bib file:

```
@inbook{Fetter_Walecka,
  author       = {A.~L.~Fetter and J.~D.~Walecka}, 
  title        = {Theoretical Mechanics of Particles and Continua},
  publisher    = {Dover},
  year         = 2003,
  address      = {New York},
  chapter      = 33,
}
```

I would like to modify the displayed result in such a way to replace "Chap." with "Sec."

I am using the `apsrev4-1` bibliography style.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: You should replace `author   = {A.~L.~Fetter and J.~D.~Walecka},` with `author = {A. L. Fetter and J. D. Walecka},`, i.e., replace the four instances of `~` with ordinary, i.e., line-breakable, whitespace. Better still, write `author = {Alexander L. Fetter and John D. Walecka},` which will come in handy if you ever use a bibliography style that doesn't truncate authors' given names.

Comment: @Mico Many thanks for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to supplying the optional `type` field, as you've demonstrated in your answer, you may also want to (a) change the name of the `title` field to `booktitle` and (b) back-fill the real `title` field as well as the corresponding `pages` field. The reason for suggesting these changes is that you're not really citing an entire book but just a brief part; hence, your readers may appreciate if you furnish this information up front.

Alternatively, you could just create an entry of type `@book` and use the citation call-out to specify which part of the full publication is being cited. E.g.,

```
@book{Fetter_Walecka,
  author       = {Alexander L. Fetter and John D. Walecka}, 
  booktitle    = {Theoretical Mechanics of Particles and Continua},
  publisher    = {Dover},
  address      = {New York},
  year         = 2003,
}
```

along with

```
\citep[sec.~33]{Fetter_Walecka}
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@inbook{Fetter_Walecka,
  author       = {Alexander L. Fetter and John D. Walecka}, 
  title        = {Example: Charged Particle in an Electromagnetic Field},
  booktitle    = {Theoretical Mechanics of Particles and Continua},
  publisher    = {Dover},
  address      = {New York},
  year         = 2003,
  chapter      = 33,
  type         = "sec.",
  pages        = "179-180",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}

\begin{document}
\cite{Fetter_Walecka}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the field "type", as follows:

```
@inbook{Fetter_Walecka,
  author       = {A.~L.~Fetter and J.~D.~Walecka}, 
  title        = {Theoretical Mechanics of Particles and Continua},
  publisher    = {Dover},
  year         = 2003,
  address      = {New York},
  chapter      = 33,
  type         = "Sec."
}
```